# PyQt6 on ChromeOS (Without dev) using pyqtdeploy?

Tags: operating-system, google-chrome-os, pyqt6, androidappsonchromeos, pyqtdeploy

I wanna make an app that supports as many OS as possible(Windows, iOS, macOS, ChromeOS) so I'm trying out PyQt6 but also need it to work on a Chrome OS **WITHOUT DEVELOPER MODE**. With my experience with chromebooks, some apps in the play store downloaded on the phone can also be downloaded in the chromebook. So how do I modify my apk or xapk file to suit chromebooks?